# browsers treating JSON as text

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, symfony

I have a Symfony 2.7 application with some Ajax calls which are all about the same:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: some_url,
        data: object,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            if(data.success){
                console.log(data.success);
                //do stuff
                
            }               
        }
    })
    .fail(function(data){
        console.log('oops');
        console.log(data);
    })
    .always(function(){
        console.log('completed');
    });
```

All but one of the calls show the Request header `accepts = application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01`.  One of the calls has `accepts = text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*`. Whenever that call is made, the JSON that is returned is displayed as text instead of being processed by the `ajax.success` method.

Here is the JSON object that is returned but displayed as text:

```
{"success":true,
 "msg":"Your search was successfully saved.",
 "link":"\u003Ca  href=\u0022\/expertise\/web\/app_dev.php\/en\/search\/savedsearch\/15\u0022\u003Ebar\u003C\/a\u003E\u003Ca  class=\u0027actionlink delete\u0027 href=\u0022\/expertise\/web\/app_dev.php\/en\/search\/delsearch\u0022 data-query_id=15\u003E\u0026nbsp;\u003C\/a\u003E"
}
```

[Jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/) says it's valid.

Here is the method (from my Symfony controller) that returned the above JSON object with the Response header `content-type = application/json`. My app uses FOSJsRoutingBundle, JMSSecurityExtraBundle and JMSDiExtraBundle.

```
/**
 * @Route("/savesearch", name="exps_savesearch", options={"expose"=true})
 * @Secure(roles="ROLE_MGR, ROLE_SUP")
 * @Method("POST")
 * @return JsonResponse
 */
public function savesearchAction(Request $request){
    $ajaxinfo = new \stdClass();

    $adsearcher = $this->get('exp_adsearcher');
    $person = $adsearcher->getPersonByUserName($this->getUser()->getUsername());

    $search = new SavedSearch();
    $search->setPerson($person);

    $form = $this->createForm(new SaveSearchType,$search);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if($form->isValid()){
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($search);
            $em->flush();

            $ajaxinfo->success = true;
            $ajaxinfo->msg=$this->get('translator')->trans('message.search.save.success');
            $ajaxinfo->link = $this->renderView('ExpertiseDefaultBundle:Search:searchlink.html.twig', array('id'=>$search->getId(), 'name'=>$search->getSearchName()));
    } else {
        $ajaxinfo->success = false;
        $ajaxinfo->msg= $this->renderView('ExpertiseDefaultBundle:Form:formerrors_ajax.html.twig',array('form'=>$form->createView()));
    }
    return new JsonResponse($ajaxinfo);
}
```

Why is Request header `accepts = text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*` when `ajax.dataType: json`? And is this why all browsers treat this JSON as text?

## ETA:

The comments from @Quentin and @Mike Brant about a form submission over-riding the ajax call are probably right on target. Here's the code that wraps the ajax call:

```
$('form[name="savesearchform"]').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var frm = this;
    $('.error',$(frm)).remove();
    $('#delsearch_msg').empty();
    $('#savesearch_msg').empty();
    $.ajax({ /* as above */ }).fail(function(data){ /* as above */ }).always(function(){ /* as above */ });
});
```

I would have thought that `e.preventDefault();` would, well, prevent the default action. But perhaps not.  So how do I fix it?

Comment: If you're sending `text/html`, it's not really a big suprise that jQuery doesn't parse it for you, it thinks it's ... wait for it ... `text/html` ?

Comment: Are you sure the header isn't set by the webserver itself? I recently went crazy over a CORS header set by nginx (which I had added myself, but forgot about).

Comment: Try this 
success: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    var data = $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);

Comment: @MuhammadShoaib doing parseJSON is not right way. cuz jquery understands by content-type that the information is json and automaticaly make json object

Comment: @adeneo — The code says `dataType: 'json',`, that makes jQuery ignore the content-type header.

Comment: "One of the calls has accepts = text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*." — That won't happen when you say `dataType: 'json',`. Some other code (possibly a regular form submission) is triggering that request.

Comment: My thinking would be along the lines of what @Quentin noted.  Is there some sort of default form submission taking place here that is not being prevented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is embarrassing. I found a typo in the html which meant that the form names didn't match so the javascript was never called.

I appreciate everyone's help and have upvoted where I could.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's strange cuz JsonResponse must return proper headers.
but how about this?

```
$response = new Response();
$response->setContent(json_encode($ajaxinfo));
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
return $response;
```

also in here http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html You can see example of using JsonResponse. try also this:

```
$response = new JsonResponse();
$response->setData(get_object_vars($ajaxinfo));
return $response;
```

if problem still persist after it, I think maybe there is filter somewhere that replaces header. have to debug.

Comment: You're right, JsonResponse will return the proper headers. It not returning the right headers doesn't explain the problem though. The JavaScript is set up to ignore the content-type, and even if it wasn't, having the wrong headers wouldn't cause it to be *displayed* instead of parsed as JSON.

Comment: I'd already tried the first suggestion to no avail. Just tried the 2nd suggestion and still no joy. :( So more debugging I guess. I've updated my question to show the containing javascript. It's likely that @Quentin is correct and somehow the form is setting the header despite `preventDefault()` being called.

Comment: maybe try this: $('form[name="savesearchform"]').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation(); console.log('savesearchform handled'); ...

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to encode a StdClass, before serializing to Json you need to cast the StdClass to an array :

```
return new JsonResponse((array) $ajaxinfo);
```

The JsonResponse object serializes **raw** objects, you get text format because there is double serialization.

Comment: StdClass serializes just fine for the other calls that aren't causing me problems. But, to test your hypothesis, I tried your suggestion. I got the same result as with StdClass.